# Maximum of parametrized expression

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

given numbers $0\le a,b,c,d\le1,a+b+c+d=1$. Find numbers $0\le\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\le1$ with sum equaled to $1$, such that expression $(a-d)(\beta-\gamma)+b(-\alpha+\gamma+\delta)+c(\alpha-\beta-\delta)$ is maximal.

Is there any "easy" way to solve this?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum can't be in the interior since the objective function is linear in the variables. Which boundary point maximizes it depends on $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. For instance, for $c=1$ the maximum is at $\alpha=1$; for $a=1$ the maximum is at $\beta=1$; for $d=1$ the maximum is at $\gamma=1$; and for $b=1$ any point with $\gamma+\delta=1$ is a maximum.